# ASP Downloading file using TransmitFile()

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, zip, filenames

I am using Response.TransmitFile() to download a zip folder from a folder on my C drive. The folder downloads fine and i get the files turn up in my downloads folder. However the problem is in my downloads folder, with a zip file that has the name of the asp page, and inside is the folder that i wanted to download. The other problem is i append a DataTime on the end of the  zip folder in the upload, but the date is not on the end of the folder name either.

My Upload Code looks like this:

```
string pnq = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace(pnq, "/");
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
        var filename = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
        var uriID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var password = System.Web.Security.Membership.GeneratePassword(7, 2);
        filename = filename.Remove(filename.Count() - 4) + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + ".zip";
        filename = filename.Replace(" ", "-");
        filename = filename.Replace("/", "-");
        FileUpload1.SaveAs("C:\\Uploads\\" + filename);
        lblUri.Text = url + "UICDownload.aspx?fileID=" + uriID;
        lblPassword.Text = password;
        string file = MapPath("~/Sample.xml");
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);
        doc.Root.Add(new XElement("File", new XElement("name", filename), new XElement("uriID", uriID), new XElement("password", password)));
        XElement name = new XElement("name", filename);
        doc.Save(file);
}
```

My Download Code looks like this:

```
    var text = Request.QueryString["fileID"];
    string file = MapPath("~/Sample.xml");
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);
    var node = doc.Document.Descendants("uriID").FirstOrDefault(u => u.Value.Equals(text));
    var filenode = node.Ancestors("File").First();
    var tempname = filenode.Element("name");
    var filename = tempname.Value.ToString();
    var filePassword = filenode.Element("password");
    if (filePassword.Value.ToString() == tbPassword.Text)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; fileID=" + text);
        Response.TransmitFile("C:\\Uploads\\" + filename);
        Response.End();
    }
```

The XML Document im saving to looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rootElement>
  <File>
    <name>Pictures-21-06-2013.zip</name>
    <uriID>96e1253b-634b-498a-b062-61a1a097ee3f</uriID>
    <password>%zFxRr|</password>
  </File>
  <File>
    <name>Test1-21-06-2013.zip</name>
    <uriID>44d3d2c8-5c19-4f79-a5e2-66bb023a4d5e</uriID>
    <password>{hik6.e</password>
   </File>
```

Please any suggestions are welcome, and let me know if you would like me to show any other code. Also just to add, when the files are uploaded into the C:\Uploads folder, the zip folders have the date at the end of their names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this line to the following:

```
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
```

Comment: As for the nesting of the zip files, if you zip a folder then it creates that folder nested inside your zip file. When you create the zip, just zip up the files (hope that makes sense?)